# Trying to make a spring application to web mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I had a working spring jdbc project in eclipse.
I am trying to make it mvc, so I have added `web.xml` and other spring mvc configuration files, including web-mvc dependency in `pom.xml`.

My project structure looks like this:
[image]

I am having trouble is: I am not getting option to run it on server. I have tried added tomcat in run configuration, but is giving

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
```

Could someone please help, what am I missing here?

Comment: PS: I have already added CATALINA_HOME in environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  project properties -> project facets,

check whether the Dyanamic Web module is enabled. When we are creating a web project, this is enabled by our IDE.  Check whether it helps

[image: ProjectFacets]

Now Check whether your deployment assembly points the correct webapps folder which contains the web.xml

[image: deployment assembly]

Comment: Sounds correct but it gave many errors in my project. `web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true` in `pom.xml`

Comment: Edited the answer for additional steps